# Openlayers 3 equivalent of Openlayers 2 offline storage

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I found this link: http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/offline-storage.html which you can use openlayers 2 for offline storage. Is this still possible for Openlayers 3? I read their docs and ol.control doesn't have CacheWrite and CacheRead anymore.. I'm still a beginner, so I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no OL3 equivalent, you can try on TileStache - https://github.com/TileStache/TileStache and use the tiles saved on a `ol.source.XYZ`.